# Firebase cloud messaging in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am new to cordova, I have created a cordova app and run successfully, now I need to integrate a push notification in it. So i gone with google **Firebase**, i have created all the dependencies for firebase and downloaded **google.services.json** . And i have added listener in **index.js** file (refered  [this link](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)) also, no problem upto this. In the firebase Document, asked to add these lines at app level build grade

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this at buildscript `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

After adding this am using command `cordova build android` , it throws error. Am not sure what is wrong
**Note :**
Also tried without adding the above line, in that case, build gets success but the notification is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official phonegap plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). This would give you a fair idea on how to do or alternatively if it meets your use case you can directly use it.

Cordova is a free version of phone-gap so compatibility will not be an issue.